# Does deleting nodes generally cause severe garbage collection?

Tags: neo4j

I have a neo4J VM set to use 6G of RAM. Neo has been allocated 3G of heap.  I created about 600,000 nodes, and then began deleting them with a program I call a reaper. After deleting about 200,000 nodes, my reaper code started running about 10x slower. I had turned on Neo gc logging and the log file is just rolling and rolling, and has been for a quite a while now.  Both CPU cores allocated to the VM are pegged.

I don't really know why the garbage collector started freaking out. Does deleting nodes cause this? Everything was running well.  Then BOOM.

Comment: What version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: @cybersam 2.3.1, as of today.